# Perform action when focused

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs. 2 of them change their color when focused. Can also an action be performed on another div when 2 of them get focused?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.myClass:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" tabindex="-1">
  Focus me!
</div>
<div class="myClass" tabindex="-1">
  You can focus me too!
</div>
<hr />
<div class="anotherClass">
  I cannot be focused, but want to change my color, when one of the other divs above me get focused.
</div>
```

So when 1 of the 2 upper divs get focused I want the 3rd div at the bottom to change its color.

Here you can have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/ogpvvwtg/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
.myClass:focus ~ .anotherClass {
    background-color: red;
    outline: none;
}
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  .myClass:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
    outline: none;
  }
  .myClass:focus ~ .anotherClass {
    background-color: red;
    outline: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="myClass" tabindex="-1">
  Focus me!
</div>
<div class="myClass" tabindex="-1">
  You can focus me too!
</div>
<hr />
<div class="anotherClass">
  I cannot be focused, but want to change my color, when one of the other divs above me get focused.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a little bit of javascript which might give you more control of the things you want to color.

```js
colorDiv3 = function() {
  window.document.getElementById("div3").style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
}
```

```css
  div {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  .myClass:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
    outline: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="myClass" tabindex="-1" onFocus="colorDiv3()">
  Focus me!
</div>
<div class="myClass" tabindex="-1" onFocus="colorDiv3()">
  You can focus me too!
</div>
<hr />
<div id="div3" class="anotherClass">
  I cannot be focused, but want to change my color, when one of the other divs above me get focused.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this using JavaScript:

First give the divs IDs:

```
<div id="topDiv" class="myClass" tabindex="-1">
```

etc...

Then you can find them with:

```
var top_div = document.getElementById('top_div');
var middle_div = document.getElementById('middle_div');
var bottom_div = document.getElementById('bottom_div');
```

Assign an event listener to the objects. This allows you to call a function when an element is focused:

```
top_div.addEventListener("focus", changeBottomDivColor);
middle_div.addEventListener("focus", changeBottomDivColor);
```

And finally, the function to actually change the color:

```
function changeBottomDivColor() {
    bottom_div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```